# lwjgl 3 glDrawElement EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: java, exception, lwjgl, access-violation

when i try to follow the ThinMatrix OpenGL tutorial on lwjgl 3 but when go to run the code for testing indices, return an EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION on glDrawElement() function.

**Error code**

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000073eb7436, pid=5024, tid=0x0000000000001460
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_101-b13) (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.101-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [nvoglv64.DLL+0xab7436]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000001df25800):  JavaThread "MainThread" [_thread_in_native, id=5216, stack(0x000000001ebd0000,0x000000001ecd0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000005

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000006, RBX=0x0000000000000000, RCX=0x00014dcd46f1a00a, RDX=0x000000898dd4c83f
RSP=0x000000001eccf000, RBP=0x0000000000000006, RSI=0x0000000020210080, RDI=0x0000000020210080
R8 =0x000000000000009a, R9 =0x0000000000000000, R10=0x0000000000000001, R11=0x0000000075a3b4a0
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x0000000020210828, R14=0x0000000000001401, R15=0x0000000000000000
RIP=0x0000000073eb7436, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000001eccf000)
0x000000001eccf000:   0000000000000004 000000001df25800
0x000000001eccf010:   0000000000000000 000000001eccf208
0x000000001eccf020:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000001eccf030:   000000001eccf000 0000000000000000
0x000000001eccf040:   0000000000000000 00007ff83b9cd8c0
0x000000001eccf050:   0000000000000004 0000000000000006
0x000000001eccf060:   000000001b9bb240 0000000000001401
0x000000001eccf070:   000000001b9ce478 0000000000000000
0x000000001eccf080:   0000000000000000 0000000073b8bb06
0x000000001eccf090:   0000000020210828 0000000000000004
0x000000001eccf0a0:   0000000020210080 000000001de03770
0x000000001eccf0b0:   0000000000000006 0000000000000006
0x000000001eccf0c0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000001eccf0d0:   000000001b9bb200 000000001df25800
0x000000001eccf0e0:   000000001b9ce478 00000000024e77a6
0x000000001eccf0f0:   000000001df25800 000000001eccf208 

Instructions: (pc=0x0000000073eb7436)
0x0000000073eb7416:   0f b7 f8 0f b7 c1 eb 36 41 81 fe 01 14 00 00 0f
0x0000000073eb7426:   85 2c 03 00 00 48 8b 9c 24 c0 00 00 00 48 63 c5
0x0000000073eb7436:   0f b6 54 18 ff 44 0f b6 03 44 3a c2 8b ca 41 0f
0x0000000073eb7446:   47 c8 0f b6 f9 8b ca 41 0f 42 c8 0f b6 c1 2b f8 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000006 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RCX=0x00014dcd46f1a00a is an unknown value
RDX=0x000000898dd4c83f is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000001eccf000 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001df25800
RBP=0x0000000000000006 is an unknown value
RSI=0x0000000020210080 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000020210080 is an unknown value
R8 =0x000000000000009a is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R11=0x0000000075a3b4a0 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000020210828 is an unknown value
R14=0x0000000000001401 is an unknown value
R15=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x000000001ebd0000,0x000000001ecd0000],  sp=0x000000001eccf000,  free space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [nvoglv64.DLL+0xab7436]
C  [nvoglv64.DLL+0x78bb06]
C  0x00000000024e7914

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.lwjgl.system.JNI.callPV(JIIIJ)V+0
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.nglDrawElements(IIIJ)V+14
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glDrawElements(IIIJ)V+17
j  ms.renderer.Renderer.renderer(Lms/renderer/BasicVertex;)V+20
j  ms.main.MineSmooth.run()V+143
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000002300800 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=2672, stack(0x0000000002170000,0x0000000002270000)]
=>0x000000001df25800 JavaThread "MainThread" [_thread_in_native, id=5216, stack(0x000000001ebd0000,0x000000001ecd0000)]
  0x000000001de96800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6372, stack(0x000000001e9d0000,0x000000001ead0000)]
  0x000000001de14800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6324, stack(0x000000001e8d0000,0x000000001e9d0000)]
  0x000000001de08000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2936, stack(0x000000001e7d0000,0x000000001e8d0000)]
  0x000000001de00800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9800, stack(0x000000001e6d0000,0x000000001e7d0000)]
  0x000000001ddfc800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5268, stack(0x000000001e5d0000,0x000000001e6d0000)]
  0x000000001ddf7800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8176, stack(0x000000001e4d0000,0x000000001e5d0000)]
  0x000000001bf1e800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6508, stack(0x000000001e3d0000,0x000000001e4d0000)]
  0x00000000023f9000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6072, stack(0x000000001e1d0000,0x000000001e2d0000)]
  0x00000000023f8000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9308, stack(0x000000001dcd0000,0x000000001ddd0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x000000001bf09000 VMThread [stack: 0x000000001dbd0000,0x000000001dcd0000] [id=3876]
  0x000000001deb1000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x000000001ead0000,0x000000001ebd0000] [id=1512]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 76288K, used 14593K [0x000000076b300000, 0x0000000770800000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 65536K, 22% used [0x000000076b300000,0x000000076c1407d8,0x000000076f300000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0x000000076fd80000,0x000000076fd80000,0x0000000770800000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x000000076f300000,0x000000076f300000,0x000000076fd80000)
 ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 0K [0x00000006c1800000, 0x00000006cc300000, 0x000000076b300000)
  object space 175104K, 0% used [0x00000006c1800000,0x00000006c1800000,0x00000006cc300000)
 Metaspace       used 8247K, capacity 8485K, committed 8832K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 702K, capacity 771K, committed 896K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000011890000,0x0000000012090000] byte_map_base: 0x000000000e284000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x000000007602a6d0
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000012de0000, 0x0000000016d80000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000016d80000, 0x000000001ad20000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000a20000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=2281Kb max_used=2281Kb free=243478Kb
 bounds [0x00000000024d0000, 0x0000000002740000, 0x00000000114d0000]
 total_blobs=1236 nmethods=463 adapters=687
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 1.025 Thread 0x000000001de14800  459  s    3       java.util.Vector::addElement (38 bytes)
Event: 1.026 Thread 0x000000001de14800 nmethod 459 0x00000000027095d0 code [0x0000000002709760, 0x0000000002709c88]
Event: 1.028 Thread 0x000000001de14800  460       3       java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream::fill (80 bytes)
Event: 1.028 Thread 0x000000001de14800 nmethod 460 0x0000000002709e90 code [0x000000000270a020, 0x000000000270a408]
Event: 1.028 Thread 0x000000001de14800  461   !   3       java.util.zip.Inflater::setInput (74 bytes)
Event: 1.029 Thread 0x000000001de14800 nmethod 461 0x000000000270a5d0 code [0x000000000270a760, 0x000000000270ac98]
Event: 1.029 Thread 0x000000001de14800  462       3       java.net.URL::toString (5 bytes)
Event: 1.029 Thread 0x000000001de14800 nmethod 462 0x000000000270ae90 code [0x000000000270b000, 0x000000000270b2e8]
Event: 1.029 Thread 0x000000001de14800  463       3       java.net.URL::toExternalForm (9 bytes)
Event: 1.029 Thread 0x000000001de14800 nmethod 463 0x000000000270b3d0 code [0x000000000270b540, 0x000000000270b768]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (8 events):
Event: 0.032 Thread 0x0000000002300800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BII)Ljava/lang/Class; name or signature does not match> (0x000000076b307cc0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\sŽ+8Î\O ?
Event: 0.032 Thread 0x0000000002300800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.prefetchRead(Ljava/lang/Object;J)V name or signature does not match> (0x000000076b307fa8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\„•!‡§Ã?
Event: 0.149 Thread 0x000000001df25800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x000000076b8234c8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1146]
Event: 0.150 Thread 0x000000001df25800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x000000076b830a30) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1146]
Event: 0.180 Thread 0x000000001df25800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076b8db118) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.180 Thread 0x000000001df25800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076b8db510) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.181 Thread 0x000000001df25800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076b8df528) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.181 Thread 0x000000001df25800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076b8df920) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]

Events (10 events):
Event: 1.032 loading class org/lwjgl/opengl/NVVertexBufferUnifiedMemory
Event: 1.032 loading class org/lwjgl/opengl/NVVertexBufferUnifiedMemory done
Event: 1.033 loading class org/lwjgl/opengl/NVXConditionalRender
Event: 1.033 loading class org/lwjgl/opengl/NVXConditionalRender done
Event: 1.034 loading class ms/utils/Buffers
Event: 1.034 loading class ms/utils/Buffers done
Event: 1.035 loading class org/lwjgl/opengl/GLChecks
Event: 1.035 loading class org/lwjgl/opengl/GLChecks done
Event: 1.035 loading class ms/renderer/BasicVertex
Event: 1.035 loading class ms/renderer/BasicVertex done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff7c0720000 - 0x00007ff7c0757000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin\javaw.exe
0x00007ff852330000 - 0x00007ff8524f1000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ff851250000 - 0x00007ff8512fd000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ff84f540000 - 0x00007ff84f728000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ff851fe0000 - 0x00007ff852087000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ff8515b0000 - 0x00007ff85164d000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ff851be0000 - 0x00007ff851c3b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\sechost.dll
0x00007ff851650000 - 0x00007ff85176c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ff8519f0000 - 0x00007ff851b46000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
0x00007ff852140000 - 0x00007ff8522c6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ff848700000 - 0x00007ff848974000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.10586.494_none_a2d8b04ea53e3145\COMCTL32.dll
0x00007ff851c40000 - 0x00007ff851ebd000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\combase.dll
0x00007ff84eb00000 - 0x00007ff84eb6a000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x00007ff852100000 - 0x00007ff85213b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x0000000075570000 - 0x0000000075642000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x0000000075810000 - 0x00000000760aa000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ff851ec0000 - 0x00007ff851ec8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ff848be0000 - 0x00007ff848be9000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ff84c300000 - 0x00007ff84c323000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007ff84a420000 - 0x00007ff84a42a000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007ff851b70000 - 0x00007ff851bdb000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x0000000000970000 - 0x000000000099c000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x00007ff84f4d0000 - 0x00007ff84f513000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x0000000075720000 - 0x000000007572f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin\verify.dll
0x00000000756f0000 - 0x0000000075719000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin\java.dll
0x00000000756d0000 - 0x00000000756e6000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin\zip.dll
0x00007ff84f7a0000 - 0x00007ff850cfc000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007ff84ee80000 - 0x00007ff84f4c5000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\windows.storage.dll
0x00007ff851ed0000 - 0x00007ff851f22000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\shlwapi.dll
0x00007ff84e950000 - 0x00007ff84e95f000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x00007ff84e9e0000 - 0x00007ff84ea95000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\shcore.dll
0x00007ff84e990000 - 0x00007ff84e9db000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\powrprof.dll
0x00007ff84e970000 - 0x00007ff84e984000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\profapi.dll
0x00007ff83b980000 - 0x00007ff83ba4e000     A:\Java Programming\Library\LWJGL 3\native\lwjgl.dll
0x00007ff851460000 - 0x00007ff8515a3000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
0x00007ff84e3f0000 - 0x00007ff84e3fb000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.DLL
0x00007ff847070000 - 0x00007ff8470ac000     A:\Java Programming\Library\LWJGL 3\native\glfw.dll
0x00007ff84d180000 - 0x00007ff84d216000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x00007ff846870000 - 0x00007ff8468b1000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dinput8.dll
0x00007ff8489b0000 - 0x00007ff8489be000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\xinput1_4.dll
0x00007ff84d150000 - 0x00007ff84d177000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x00007ff84bb10000 - 0x00007ff84bb32000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dwmapi.dll
0x00007ff834340000 - 0x00007ff834469000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\opengl32.dll
0x00007ff846de0000 - 0x00007ff846e0e000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\GLU32.dll
0x00007ff837480000 - 0x00007ff83757a000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DDRAW.dll
0x00007ff848980000 - 0x00007ff848988000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DCIMAN32.dll
0x00007ff84d710000 - 0x00007ff84d71c000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\HID.DLL
0x00007ff850e10000 - 0x00007ff851239000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SETUPAPI.DLL
0x00007ff84eaa0000 - 0x00007ff84eaf5000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINTRUST.dll
0x00007ff84e960000 - 0x00007ff84e970000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x00007ff84eb70000 - 0x00007ff84ed38000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x00007ff8452c0000 - 0x00007ff845305000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\vulkan-1.dll
0x00007ff8341b0000 - 0x00007ff83433c000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\Dbghelp.dll
0x00007ff84de40000 - 0x00007ff84de71000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntmarta.dll
0x00007ff851300000 - 0x00007ff85145a000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x0000000073400000 - 0x0000000075570000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\nvoglv64.DLL
0x00007ff84b710000 - 0x00007ff84b723000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WTSAPI32.dll
0x00007ff84e430000 - 0x00007ff84e486000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINSTA.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Djava.library.path=A:\Java Programming\Library\LWJGL 3\native -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
java_command: ms.main.MineSmooth
java_class_path (initial): A:\Java Programming\Game\MineSmooth Engien\bin;A:\Java Programming\Library\LWJGL 3\jar\lwjgl.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_101/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_101/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_101/lib/amd64;A:\C++ Programming\Library\Vulkan 1.0.21.1\Bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\Users\ottet\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin";C:\Program Files (x86)\Autodesk\Backburner\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Users\ottet\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Docfa4\PGM;C:\WINDOWS\System32;
USERNAME=ottet
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=AMD64 Family 21 Model 2 Stepping 0, AuthenticAMD



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 10.0 , 64 bit Build 10586 (10.0.10586.0)

CPU:total 8 (8 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 21 model 2 stepping 0, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, clmul, mmxext, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, sse4a, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv, bmi1

Memory: 4k page, physical 16675024k(13021908k free), swap 19165392k(15118524k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.101-b13) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_101-b13), built on Jun 22 2016 01:21:29 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Mon Sep 05 20:19:13 2016
elapsed time: 1 seconds (0d 0h 0m 1s)
```

I've simplify the code, maybe the error it's more evident:

**EDITED**

**VertexArrayObject**

```
package ms.renderer;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.*;

import ms.utils.Buffers;

public class VertexArrayObject {

    private int vaoID;
    private int vboID;
    private int indexID;
    private int vertexCount;

    public VertexArrayObject() {

    }

    public void init() {

        float[] positions = new float[]{

                -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
                -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
                 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
                 0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
        };

        int[] indices = new int[]{

                0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2

        };

        vertexCount = indices.length;

        vaoID = glGenVertexArrays();
        glBindVertexArray(vaoID);

        vboID = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers.createFloatBuffer(positions), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        indexID = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexID);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers.createIntBuffer(indices), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }

    public void render() {

        glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, vertexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    public void cleanUp() {

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glDeleteBuffers(vboID);
        glDeleteBuffers(indexID);

        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glDeleteVertexArrays(vaoID);
    }
}
```

**MainClass**

```
package ms.main;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

import ms.input.KeyboardInput;
import ms.renderer.VertexArrayObject;
import ms.utils.FinalVariables;

public class MainClass implements Runnable {

    private Thread thread;

    private static Display display = new Display();
    private static VertexArrayObject render = new VertexArrayObject();

    private static int WIDTH = FinalVariables.WIDTH;
    private static int HEIGHT = FinalVariables.HEIGHT;
    private static String TITLE = FinalVariables.TITLE;

    private boolean isRunning = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MainClass game = new MainClass();

        display = new Display(WIDTH, HEIGHT, TITLE);
        game.start();
    }

    public void start() {

        isRunning = true;

        thread = new Thread(this, "MainThread");
        thread.start();
    }

    public void run() {

        display.init();

        createCapabilities();
        display.libVersion();

        render.init();

        while(isRunning) {

            update();
            render();
            render.render();


            if(glfwWindowShouldClose(display.window)) {
                isRunning = false;
            }
        }

        render.cleanUp();
    }

    public void update() {

        if(KeyboardInput.isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE)) {
            isRunning = false;
        }

        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    public void render() {

        glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glfwSwapBuffers(display.window);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    }
}
```

**Buffers**

```
package ms.utils;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;

public class Buffers {

    public static ByteBuffer createByteBuffer(byte[] data) {

        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(data.length).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        buffer.put(data);
        buffer.flip();

        return buffer;
    }

    public static FloatBuffer createFloatBuffer(float[] data) {

        FloatBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(data.length << 2).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        buffer.put(data);
        buffer.flip();

        return buffer;
    }

    public static IntBuffer createIntBuffer(int[] data) {

        IntBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(data.length << 2).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asIntBuffer();
        buffer.put(data);
        buffer.flip();

        return buffer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read very far in the code, but one problem jumps out very quickly. You're using `int` for the index type:

```
int[] indices = {
        0, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 2
};
```

But then, in the draw call, you're specifying the index type as `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, vertex.getVertexCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

The type you specify here has to match the actual type of your indices. So it should be:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, vertex.getVertexCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

Another problem is that you don't have the index buffer bond when you make the draw call. You have this method:

```
private void bindIndicesBuffer(int[] indices) {
    int vboID = glGenBuffers();
    vbos.add(vboID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers.createIntBuffer(indices), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

Contrary to what the method name suggests, it does not bind the index buffer. Well, it does at first, but it unbinds it at the end, so the index buffer is nob bound when the method completes. Simply remove the last call that unbinds the index buffer, so that the VAO state contains the correct `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding.

Comment: In first time i use GL_UNSIGNED_INT and the debug return the same error, in other discussion i have found an ipotetic solution by change the GL_UNSIGNED_INT in BYTE or SHORT but the error persist. Thx for response, other idea?

Comment: @Trese Ok, added another problem to the answer.

Comment: You still don't have the index buffer bound when you make the draw call. And please don't make edits to the question that invalidate answers that were already posted. That's not how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the explanations and timely responses, I have partly solved with the solution given by judison but not completely.
Removing glEnableVertexAttribArray (0) by the render method and making all the modifications recommended by him, but I solved the problem, open the window, it was not rendered the rectangle. The problem was only the fact of the glBindVertexArray position (0). The solution, therefore, has been to move the method to the end of it all.

**VertexArrayObject**

```
package ms.renderer;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.*;

import ms.utils.Buffers;

public class VertexArrayObject {

    private int vaoID;
    private int vboID;
    private int indexID;
    private int vertexCount;

    public VertexArrayObject() {

    }

    public void init() {

        float[] positions = new float[]{

                -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
                -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
                 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
                 0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
        };

        int[] indices = new int[]{

                0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2

        };

        vertexCount = indices.length;

        vaoID = glGenVertexArrays();
        glBindVertexArray(vaoID);

        vboID = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers.createFloatBuffer(positions), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        indexID = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexID);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers.createIntBuffer(indices), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    public void render() {

        glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, vertexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    public void cleanUp() {

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glDeleteBuffers(vboID);
        glDeleteBuffers(indexID);

        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glDeleteVertexArrays(vaoID);
    }
}
```

**Thank you all for the help you have given me!**

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to enable vertexAttrib every time you go render...

```
public void render() {
    glBindVertexArray(vaoID);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, vertexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Second, don't unbind any buffer, you need the ARRAY_BUFFER and the ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER both bound to the VAO...
You can (must) unbind the vao, but the buffer's are bound to vao and you want to keep them bound.

```
    ...
    vaoID = glGenVertexArrays();
    glBindVertexArray(vaoID);

    vboID = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers.createFloatBuffer(positions), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); // enable vertex attrib here

    //glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); you dont want to unbind vbo from vao

    indexID = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexID);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers.createIntBuffer(indices), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(0); // after you done
}
```

I got the same error as you here, changed it, and worked (red screen).
Hope it helps

Comment: The `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding is not part of the state stored in the VAO.